# Artifact with ffplay at bottom of stream images

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

By getting stream of a camera with ffplay, I get artifacts like what in:

https://community-assets.home-assistant.io/original/3X/5/7/570102632dca2748a9ae9e0568f1240e4abb2a63.jpeg

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49787353/57617230-7b989c80-75aa-11e9-828d-d7706d4b10ef.jpeg

Please note that the artifact always occurs downside of images! I thought about the following:

1. not complete frames received by ffplay.
2. not correct frames received by ffplay.
3. frames received by ffplay in incorrect order.
4. not all frames are received by ffplay (frame lost.)
5. other.

This is while VLC can play the camera stream without such an effect.

BYO, What's the problem and how can I resolve it?